# Failed to allocate bytes in slab allocator for memtx_tuple Tarantool

Tags: lua, tarantool

What could be the reason for the error *"Failed to allocate 153 bytes in slab allocator for memtx_tuple"* on the client when writing to Tarantool memtx?

Comment: Explain what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

This means that memtx engine runs out of memory. Memory available for data and indexes stored in memtx is limited by `memtx_memory` option of `box.cfg`, which is default to 256Mb. It's possible to increase this limit in runtime:

```lua
-- add 512Mb
box.cfg({memtx_memory = box.cfg.memtx_memory + 512 * 2^20})
```

Here is documentation section about function for monitoring memory usage:

https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_slab/#lua-function.box.slab.info